# Wordpress WP_Query delete ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order

Tags: wordpress

I want to get posts in the order that I request.

Luckly, there was a query argument -> orderby = 'post_name__in'.

But, I get posts in other order.

And I see the query's request.

Here

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts  
WHERE 1=1  
AND wp_posts.post_name 
IN (
  'post title 1',
  'post title 2',
  'post title 3',
  ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order,
FIELD( 
  wp_posts.post_name, 
  'post title 1',
  'post title 2',
  'post title 3',
  ) 
LIMIT 0, 9
```

I find that `ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order` was a problem.

If I delete it and then Query on phpmyadmin, It works well.

I get posts in the order that I want.

So, how can I delete that `ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order` by using hook & filter or some other wordpressful way ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found answer!

the `wp_posts.menu_order` was added because of **Post Types Order** plugin.

In this plugin,

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', array($this, 'posts_orderby'), 99, 2);
~
~
~
//check for ignore_custom_sort
if (isset($query->query_vars['ignore_custom_sort']) && $query>query_vars['ignore_custom_sort'] === TRUE)
    return $orderBy;
if(trim($orderBy) == '')
  $orderBy = "{$wpdb->posts}.menu_order " . $order;
else
  $orderBy = "{$wpdb->posts}.menu_order". $order .", " . $orderBy;
~
~
return $orderBy;
```

So, I add `$args['ignore_custom_sort'] = true` to my query argument.

And this works!

Comment: You saved my day !!

Comment: You can also turn off Autosort from plugin options, that will make the order to apply only when query include a 'orderby' => 'menu_order' argument.

Comment: You are the man!!! omg this was driving me insane until I found your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, to not change directly the plugin, is removing the Post Type Order. I've found another called ' Intuitive Custom Post Order ' and it not interfer in ordering that we don't want to order, and is more complete.